# Passing redirect props to components in BrowserRouter

Tags: reactjs, redirect

I'm refactoring React code that initially works but doesn't after the refactor. I know I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out the best way to fix it. It looks like I need to try it with a completely new approach.

I've created a `router` using `createBrowserRouter` in my `App.js` file. The `router` has a `sidebar` component with different 'options' to click. When clicking the options, it redirects you to a different route. Currently, the 'redirect' functions are declared in the `sidebar` component and implement the `useNavigate` API. I'm trying to move the redirect functions to my `App.js` file so they can be used outside of just clicking on the options on the  `sidebar`. With the redirect functions and `useNavigate` declared in the `App.js` file, I get an error stating `useNavigate() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component`. Would be thankful for any help looking into the best way to refactor this

Before refactoring:

`App.js:`

```
function App() {
    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <Sidebar />,
            errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    element: <Home />
                },
                {
                    path: "decks",
                    element: <Review />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    )

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`sidebar.js:`

```
function Sidebar() {
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    
    const routeToHome = () => {
        let path ='/'
        navigate(path)
    }

    const routeToDecks = () => {
        let path = '/decks'
        navigate(path)
    }
    
    return (
        <>
        <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
            <SidebarOption logo="" title="Home" click={routeToHome} />
            <SidebarOption logo=""  title="Decks" click={routeToDecks} />
        </div>
        <div id="detail">
            <Outlet />
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

After Refactoring (it doesn't work, but I want to see what to change to make it work):

`App.js:`

```
function App() {
    let navigate = useNavigate()
    
    const routeToHome = () => {
        let path ='/'
        navigate(path)
    }

    const routeToDecks = () => {
        let path = '/decks'
        navigate(path)
    }
    
    const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <Sidebar homeRoute={routeToHome} deckRoute={routeToDecks} />,
            errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
            children: [
                {
                    path: "",
                    element: <Home />
                },
                {
                    path: "decks",
                    element: <Review />,
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
    )

    return (
        <React.StrictMode>
            <RouterProvider router={router} />
        </React.StrictMode>
    );
}

export default App;
```

`sidebar.js:`

```
const Sidebar = ({homeRoute, deckRoute}) => {
    return (
        <>
        <div className="sidebar-wrapper">
            <SidebarOption logo="" title="Home" click={homeRoute} />
            <SidebarOption logo=""  title="Decks" click={deckRoute} />
        </div>
        <div id="detail">
            <Outlet />
        </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 0):

figured i'd answer this in case anyone else runs into a similar issue. it turned out to be much easier to figure out than i had originally anticipated.

1. define your routes as strings in your `App.js` file. ex: `let homeRoute = "/"` and `let deckRoute = "/decks"`
2. pass the routes as props to your component
3. define the navigate function in your component, not in the `App.js` file
4. call the navigate function on click and pass your route as the argument. ex: `<ComponentName... onClick={() => navigate(homeRoute)} />`